# Merge pull request by Github API: SHA parameter

Tags: github

I was reading the documentation of GitHub API and I'm not sure what do do with the Merge Pull Request method.

https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#merge-a-pull-request-merge-button

Specifically with the parameter SHA. I don't understand what exactly I should provide to API.

The INPUT section says I must provide

- commit_title Title for the automatic commit message.
- commit_message Extra detail to append to automatic commit message.
- sha SHA that pull request head must match to allow merge.
- merge_method Merge method to
  use.

Where do I exactly get the sha value that I need to pass to API?

Thanks!

Comment: Each commit has a SHA (Secure Hash Algorithm), so a string like "f5dc32dc", that functions as an unique identifier for that commit. The pull request is required to provide the SHA of the last commit (the "HEAD") on the branch in question to be valid.

Comment: Thank you guys, I really appreciated. One comment if anyone reaches this post, Github expects the complete string of hash commit, not just the 7 characters (short version). If you pass the short string you will get a 422 error. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following diagram, which shows a feature branch derived from some base branch:

```
base:     ... A -- B -- C
                    \
feature:             D -- E
```

Let's suppose that we created a pull request from `feature` going back to `base`.  GitHub would execute this pull request by merging `feature` into `base`.  The pull request HEAD, at the time we created the pull request, would be commit `E` in `feature`.  But, the HEAD of the `feature` branch could change before the pull request is completed.

The API call you mention includes the `SHA-1` hash of the pull request HEAD, as a requirement for the pull request to complete.  This would avoid the possibility of `feature` being merged back to `base` while containing *additional* commits beyond commit `E`.

Regarding how you would find the `SHA-1` hash for `E`, the pull request HEAD, you may simply try using `git log`, e.g.

```
# from feature
git log
```

Then, check the output for what should be the latest entry from commit `E`, and find the hash.